# weird issue when sending a map with a value that has "," in it, as parameter in groovy

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

here is my situation:

```
func1(){
   def value1 = "gal,dan"
   def prop = ['names': value1]
   func2(prop)
}

func2(prop){
   def params_str = prop.collect { k, v -> "k=v" }.join(' ')
}
```

now i'm getting: dan has no value meaning it treats the ',' inside the first value as the ',' to go  to the next key value pair

anyone got an idea how to fix it ?

i tried encoding and decoding it but its pointless since when i decode it it still treats the ',' as go to the next key value pair

i tried sending it like ['names': "$value1"] and it failed too
i tried adding "/'gal,dan/'" and it failed too

i expect names=gal,dan

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the value1 variable with quotes to indicate that it is a single string value.

```
func1() {
   def value1 = "gal,dan"
   def prop = ['names': "'$value1'"]
   func2(prop)
 }

func2(prop) {
   def params_str = prop.collect { k, v -> "k=$v" }.join(' ')
 }
```